# Print on Safari without borders

Tags: css, pdf, printing, safari, export

I wrote my letterhead in HTML, CSS and PHP.

When I print the letter, Safari will always add some borders around the letter and transforms some things to fit - Crome doesn't.

I made a "Print" with Jquery that it only prints the A4 DIV with the right dimensions.

I also found a Export to PDF Button in Safari, but this also doesn't work, because it is not @media print in css.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but this is not possible on Safari. The rendering of the margins ad borders of the page cannot be set on Safari. You can instead render this document on the server and send the output document to the user. Here you need not depend on the browser to render your document

Comment: Ok, tanks for that. What is the best way to render the PDF with the Stylesheet?

Comment: Can I style the "Export as PDF" option in Safari?